# add a slash at the end of website url using web.config re-write rule?

Tags: php, wordpress, iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config

I am working on a wordpress website. I want to add a slash at the end of website url if it is not exist into url.

If any one request for this url : `www.mydomain.com/page/subpage`, it's pragmatically convert into `www.mydomain.com/page/subpage/`(append a slash at the end of the url). I want this because when user request for  `www.mydomain.com/page/subpage` url it's give me url not found error.

For url re-writing i use following Rule in my `web.config` file:

web.config rule:

```
<rule name="Add trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">  
  <match url="(.*[^/])$" />  
  <conditions>  
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />  
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />  
  </conditions>  
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}/" />  
</rule>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what doesn't work?

Answer (score -2):

Try this

EXAMPLE – REDIRECT ALL URLS THAT DOESN’T HAVE A TRAILING SLASH TO URLS WITH A TRAILING SLASH

create a .htaccess rewrite rule

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```